# Implement Regular Expression code without adding reference to RegEx library

Tags: regex, vba

I developed a macro that matches a number pattern in the subject line. I am using the RegEx library and the following code segment:

```
orderRegExp.Pattern = ".*\d{4}.*$"
```

We are running into difficulty when rolling this out via Group Policy as adding references dynamically did not work.

I need to re-write the macro in such a way that it can find four or more consecutive numbers within a string without using Regular Expressions.  Positive matches should, for example be "Please see T2342 for more detail" or "Job Number 4763". Negative matches should be "Please see T123 for reference" or "Check Page 456".

**Final Implemented Solution:**

```
Function RegResult(SubjectString As String) As Boolean

Dim re As Object
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
    .Pattern = ".*\d{4}.*$"
    RegResult = .test(SubjectString)
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try Late binding way:

```
Dim regex as Object
Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
```

It does NOT need setting a reference like in Early binding...

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I've added the implemented solution above.